# Wordpress WP_Query with meta_query get values by Like

Tags: wordpress, wildcard, sql-like, meta-key

I'm building a custom search. 
On this i'm trying to get posts where the searched text should be used as a wild card to compare within 2 meta_key.

Below is my code,

```
<?php $args = (

    array(
        'post_type' => 'registration',
        'meta_key'=>'rg_upload_video',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'rg_first_name',
                'value' => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'rg_last_name',
                'value' => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
    );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

As a result it's simply returning all posts having **Meta_key** as **rg_upload_video**. I need the posts having searched text in meta_key **rg_first_name** or **rg_last_name**.

Did anyone know where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `'meta_key'=>'rg_upload_video',` ?

Comment: no because that's the first condition. Post should have this meta key and second condition is filter those by name (first name / last name)

Comment: I don't think that you can do both an `AND` and an `OR` in the same `meta_query`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do two `WP_Query` queries. In the first one you select all that has the `rg_upload_video` meta key. Then you do another WP_Query that searches only the posts obtained in the first query. Not tested, but it should look like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'registration',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'=>'rg_upload_video',
);

$videos = new WP_Query($args);

# get list of posts containing meta key rg_upload_video
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $videos->posts, 'ID' );

# You then do another WP_Query to get the posts having postmeta first name or last nav_menu_description

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'registration',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'rg_first_name',
            'value' => $s,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rg_last_name',
            'value' => $s,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Custom SQL query will be better than running 2 WP_Query unnecessarily.

Comment: you could also use transients to store the post IDs if you need the query often

Answer (score -2):

Try running the below code.

```
<?php $args =  array(
        'post_type' => 'registration',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                'key' => 'rg_first_name',
                'value' => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              ),
              array(
                'key' => 'rg_last_name',
                'value' => $s,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
              )
            ),
            array(
               'key' => 'rg_upload_video',
               'compare' => 'EXISTS' 
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
    );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

Comment: That's not true. AFAIK, you can't put two relationship in the meta_query

Comment: Then I guess, Custom SQL query is the only way if the above query does not work.

Comment: No, WP_Query is enough.